# Indent all tags with Vim

Tags: html, vim

How do can I add a level of indentation for all HTML tags in Vim similar to how it handles XML?

Examples:

Vim indentation using HTML format. Only certain tags are indented:

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<div class="row">
   <aside class="span4">
   <section>
   <h1>
      <%= gravatar_for @user %>
      <%= @user.name %>
   </h1>
   </section>
   </aside>
</div>
```

Vim indentation using XML format. All tags are indented:

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<div class="row">
   <aside class="span4">
      <section>
         <h1>
            <%= gravatar_for @user %>
            <%= @user.name %>
         </h1>
      </section>
   </aside>
</div>
```

I would like my HTML indentation to have one indent for every tag, just like the XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be using HTML5 but Vim's HTML-related scripts don't work with HTM5.

You need an updated HTML5 indent script for Vim to recognise those new tags. Try vim.org or Github.

The XML indent script works because XML doesn't have a predefined set of tags so the script is designed to accomodate with whatever tags you throw at it.

Comment: Do you have a html.vim you could recommend?

Comment: No. I've seen a couple of them floating around but I don't do HTML5 so I never bookmarked them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `=` and with the full combination of:

```
gg=G
```

As makes changes from the beginning of the file (gg) til its end (G).